# Java Vertx extract Files from multipart form data

Tags: java, inputstream, vert.x

Suppose I have

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.post("/").handler(ctx ->{
    //body..
}
```

I know that `Set<FileUpload> set = ctx.fileUploads();` will give me a set of my files. The issue I have is that I don't actually get the files - that is, if `s` is `FileUpload` something like `InputStream f = s.getAsInputStream()` does not exist. In other frameworks this is an option. Is there a way to get the files as input streams?

Comment: Could you provide an example from another framework that does it, so it would be easier to understand what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a two-step approach to access the file contents in the past:

1. Use `FileUpload.uploadedFileName()` to get the path to the locally stored file that was uploaded.
2. Use some variant of `FileSystem.readFile(String path)`, which yields a `Buffer` type, which contains a reference to the raw bytes.

That Rx-ified version of that would look something like this:

```
FileSystem fileSystem = ctx.vertx().fileSystem();

Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.post("/").handler(ctx -> {
  ctx.fileUploads()
    .map({ fileUpload ->
      return fileSystem.rxReadFile(fileUpload.uploadedFileName())
          .map({ buffer ->
            return buffer.bytes;  // <-- here's the binary content
          });
    })
```